# How to download data in CursorLoader if getSupportLoader() is not working?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to create CursorLoader for downloading data not in main thread. For displaying data I use `ListView` and `CursorAdapter`. But when I set adapter using `getSupportLoaderManager()`(because `getLoaderManager()` is not working) `ListView` stays empty. Maybe, it's because this method is deprecated?   But what I should use instead of it?
I will be thankful for any help.
P.S. It's working when I download data without `CursorLoader`.

My code in `OnCreate()` :

```
memberCursorAdapter = new MemberCursorAdapter(this, null, false);
listViewMembers.setAdapter(memberCursorAdapter);
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(MEMBER_LOADER, null, MainActivity.this);
```

Methods for CursorLoader

```
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, @Nullable Bundle args) {
        String projection[] = {
                MemberEntry._ID,
                MemberEntry.KEY_FIRST_NAME,
                MemberEntry.KEY_LAST_NAME,
                MemberEntry.KEY_GENDER,
                MemberEntry.KEY_SPORT
        };
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, MemberEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                projection, null, null, null);
        return cursorLoader;
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        memberCursorAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        memberCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
```

Comment: Lately it is better to execute request in a ViewModel, and to expose the downloaded data to the Fragment using LiveData (observe with viewLifecycleOwner).

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo in this question but in `onLoadFinished()` you say "`memberCursorAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);`" where it should be `memberCursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);`

Comment: @0X0nosugar thanks, now it's working! that was really silly mistake, thank you a lot for finding it!

Comment: You're welcome :) But really consider switching over to the LiveData/ ViewModel approach if you have the time, it will be worth the trouble.